# Populate tables with Faker

Tags: php, yii2, faker

I'm struggling to work out how to use Faker with Yii2. Everything seems to be through the console, can it not be used in the web app? I'd like to see the data generated on screen and then work to insert this data into the DB once I've perfected it. I have a lot of foreign keys that I want to make sure are related properly. For instance, making sure a certain city FK has the right corresponding state FK.

I've been through and looked at the testing part on the docs and loads of google links, but this doesn't seem to be what I really need. Maybe I'm wrong? I was hoping to do something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSDh1zfz-5s

Any help at appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Faker as a web app, you can use the FakerController in Yii, as it is only set up to use as a console app.

To use it in a web app, simply set up your controller like this.

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use Faker;
use yii\web\Controller;
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionIndex() {
        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
        $titles = $faker->name(20);
        return $this->render('index', ['titles' => $titles]);
    }
}
```

It's then up to you to create the code to insert the data into your database, much like the guy did in the video.

By the way, I had no idea Faker existed, this will save me so much time in my projects! Thanks!

Comment: I'd seen Faker in my composer updates and never knew what it was too. I came across it not through Yii actually but recognized it was in the Yii app so I thought I'd watch this video and thought the same as you about the time it could save, especially for load bearing. Thanks for this answer, I had such a problem trying to get the namespace right, I really thought it had to be `yii\faker` and it wouldn't work! Fixed now!

Comment: @Jonnny generally, if you look in the composer file for an extension, you can see the autoload section. It tells you what they are loading as, and can use that in your `use` statement